# What is the log folder in MAMP?

Tags: mamp

I have a small hard drive. I am running out of space. I see that Application > Mamp > logs takes 73.97GB of space and inside that folder apache_error.log 73.96GB.

I need MAMP to work locally with php. I do not know what is that logs folder and why is it so big?. What is the best way to free space?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the default log location in MAMP 4 is `/Applications/MAMP/logs/`

You can safely delete the `apache_error.log` file. It may be useful to post a few lines of the end of that file to see what the errors are.

Answer (score 1):

The logs folder holds logs related to usage of [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) on your system. You will normally see an access log file and an error log file. The access log records which pages were accessed on your web server. You will normally see the IP address from which access occurred followed by a timestamp recording when the page was accessed followed by information that reveals the particular page that was accessed. The error log records entries related to problems with the Apache web server on your system. Those errors can be related to attempts to access nonexistent pages, problems in the code on pages, Apache configuration issues, etc. You can delete both files, but if you have a 73.96 GB error log file, you may have problems with the configuration of Apache, since that's an enormous error log file, so it would behoove you to check the contents of that file. With a file that size, you could use the [tail](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/Yosemite/man/man1/tail.html) command to examine just the last few errors recorded in the file, e.g. `tail -n 50 apache_error.log` to examine the last 50 lines. Or you could just delete it, restart Apache and check it again for any new errors that occur.

Comment: When you say that I can delete both files, what do you mean? Can I delete all the logs folder or only the apache_error.log file?

Comment: @Nrc, you should be able to delete any files within the folder. If you delete the folder itself, that may cause a problem with starting Apache, since it expects to place its log files in that folder. If you delete the 74 GB file that will free a significant amount of disk space. Apache should then be able to create new log files.  But if you don't resolve whatever problem(s) led to the error log file growing to be so large, you may eventually find the file becomes enormous again.